# C++: Deleted element still in set after calling Erase

Tags: c++, set, erase

I got a code like this:

```
for (set<GROUP*>::iterator i = Data.m_Resulting.begin(); i != Data.m_Resulting.end();)
{
    printf("Deleting %d\n", (*i)->nId);
    Data.m_MpptPool.erase(i++);
}

printf("Remains in pool: %d\n", Data.m_MpptPool.size());

// Dump Pool:

for (set<GROUP*>::iterator i = Data.m_MpptPool.begin(); i != Data.m_MpptPool.end(); i++)
{
    printf("\t %d\n", (*i)->nId);
}
```

If before deleting there was 2 objects in the set , and the firs loop deletes one of them the  .size() function shows a correct number (1)
However, the second for-loop that prints the contents of my set shows both elements in there. Later, referring to this element causes segmentation fault.
What can be the problem here?

Comment: You're first loop iterates over `m_Resulting` and your prints are done on `m_MpptPool`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not use an iterator from one `std::set` (`m_Resulting`) on another `std::set` (`m_MpptPool`). This is undefined behaviour, you need to use the value:

```
Data.m_MpptPool.erase(*it++);
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I did not figure it out myself

Answer (score 3):

Your first cycle iterates over `Data.m_Resulting`, but deletes elements in `Data.m_MpptPool`. It uses an iterator that points into the former to delete elements in the latter. That's illegal and, frankly, quite meaningless. The behavior of your code is undefined. How did you expect it to work? What did you mean by

```
Data.m_MpptPool.erase(i++);
```

when iterator `i` actually pointed into `Data.m_Resulting`?